# $u,v \in W^{1,2}(\Bbb{R})$, then $\int_\Bbb{R}{uv'}dx=-\int_\Bbb{R}{u'v}dx$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

So I need to show that, given $u,v \in W^{1,2}(\Bbb{R})$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_\Bbb{R}{uv'}dx=-\int_\Bbb{R}{u'v}dx
\end{equation}
My attempt has been this:

If $u,v \in W^{1,2}(\Bbb{R}) \Rightarrow uv\in W^{1,2}(\Bbb{R})$  with weak derivative $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$. Let $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R})$ be a test function, then:
$$\int_\Bbb{R}{(uv)\varphi'}dx=-\int_\Bbb{R}{(u'v+uv')\varphi}dx$$
$$\int_\Bbb{R}{(uv)\varphi'}dx=-\int_\Bbb{R}{u'v}\varphi dx-\int_\mathbb{R}{uv'\varphi}dx$$

As this equality holds for every test function $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R})$, I think that I need to find an adequate test function that yields the thesis.

As $u,v\in L_ {loc}^1(\Bbb{R})$ and $u',v'\in L^2(\Bbb{R})$, I suppose that said test function has something to do with the support of $u,v,u',v'$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably already know this result for $u,v \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Can you exploit the fact that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Oh, so pick a sequence $(v_n) \in C_c^\infty$ such that $v_n\rightarrow v$, right? Easier way. Thanks!